# Paramterized insert into syntax error.

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I can't tell what error I have in the syntax.

Everything seems smooth, but when I try to execute non query it gives me the error incorrect syntax near **@username**.

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(cm1,c))
            {
                #region parametrii
                //cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nickname",nicktext.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume",numetext.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenume",prenumetext.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parola",passtext.Text);
                if (Msex.Checked == true)
                {
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", Msex.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", Fsex.Text);
                }
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mailadress",mailtext.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@judet",judettext.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oras",orastext.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresa",adresatext.Text);

                #endregion
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            c.Close();
        }
```

The connection and command strings:

```
string connect = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Raul\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Db Try\Db Try\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    string cm1 = "insert into Information Values @nickname,@nume,@prenume,@parola,@sex,@mailadress,@judet,@oras,@adresa";
```

Comment: () are missing after Values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed **parentheses** for **values** in insert query

Just try this

```
string connect = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Raul\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Db Try\Db Try\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    string cm1 = "insert into Informatii Values (@nickname,@nume,@prenume,@parola,@sex,@mailadress,@judet,@oras,@adresa)";
```

Comment: i would but im new here and i dont have 15 reputation

Comment: it says that i need at least 15 for voting up